# 'The leader of' vs 'the leader in'

Tags: prepositions

> "Red Kennels, The Leader *of* Dog Training Kennels"
>
> "Red Kennels, The Leader *in* Dog Training Kennels".

Which preposition should I use—*of* or *in*?

Comment: You'd use **of** if “Dog Training Kennels” was the name of a specific company or other organisation. You'd only use **in** if it was supposed to identity a ***field of expertise*** (in which case it probably wouldn't be capitalised).

Answer (score 1):

If Red Kennels is in charge of all other dog training kennels, you would use "of". If Red Kennels is the best dog training kennel around, you would use "in". Semantics note: "the" shouldn't be capitalized.